# jQuery bookmarklet to populate a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to make a jQuery bookmarklet to populate a complex web form with some default values to reduce having to type this junk every time I go to this page.

Here is the section of the HTML code for the page:

```
     <table class="frame">
        <tr>
           <td class="frame-title">
              <div class="frame-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Personal Details&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
           </td>
           <td class="frame-title-right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2" class="frame-content">
                                         <table class="dlg-frame">
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body" width="120"><strong>Username:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="username" id="username" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>New&nbsp;Password:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="password" id="password" size="50" type="password" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Verify&nbsp;Password:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="password2" id="password2" size="50" type="password" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Last Name:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="lastname" id="lastname" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="firstname" id="firstname" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Title:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="title" id="title" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Position:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="position" id="position" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>ID-Number:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="idnumber" id="idnumber" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="phone" id="phone" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Mobile:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="mobile" id="mobile" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>e-Mail:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="email" id="email" size="50" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Birthday:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td>
                                                  <input name="birthday" id="birthday" size="10" maxlength="10" type="text" class="text" value="">
                                                  <img src="themes/tcpro/img/ico_calendar.png" id="datepicker" title="Date Picker..." alt="Date Picker..." align="middle" onmouseover="return overlib('Click here to open the date picker dialog. The date will be shown as YYYY-MM-DD in the field on the left.',SNAPX, 12, SNAPY, 12, CELLPAD, 4, 4, 4, 4, BGBACKGROUND, 'http://miavtsvn.ryder.com/Calendar/themes/tcpro/img/bg_tooltip.gif', CAPICON, 'http://miavtsvn.ryder.com/Calendar/themes/tcpro/img/ico_tt.png', CAPCOLOR, '#FFFFFF', CAPTION, 'Information', CAPTIONFONT, 'Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif', CAPTIONSIZE, '8pt', FGCOLOR, '#FFFF99');" onmouseout="return nd();">
                                                  <script type="text/javascript">
                                                     <!--
                                                     Calendar.setup({
                                                        inputField  : "birthday",     // id of the input field
                                                        ifFormat    : "%Y-%m-%d",       // format of the input field
                                                        date        : "",
                                                        button      : "datepicker",   // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
                                                        align       : "Tr",           // alignment (defaults to "Bl")
                                                        singleClick : true
                                                     });
                                                     -->
                                                  </script>
                                                  &nbsp;(Format: YYYY-MM-DD)                                                   </td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td class="dlg-body"><strong>Gender:</strong></td>
                                      <td class="dlg-body">
                                         <input name="opt_gender" id="utmale" type="radio" value="ut_male" CHECKED>Male                                             &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                         <input name="opt_gender" id="utfemale" type="radio" value="ut_female">Female                                          </td>
                                   </tr>
                                </table>

            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
                                   </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>
                 </div>
```

Now here is the jQuery I'm attempting to use to populate at least some of these fields.
    (function(win, doc, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';

```
// Don't run if jQuery isn't loaded
if (typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined') {
  return;
}

// Our code will go here.

  }(window, window.document, window.jQuery));

//$('#name').val(data.name);
$("#username").val("jdoe");
$('#password').val('password');
$('#password2').val('password');
$('#lastname').val('Doe');
$('#firstname').val('John');
$('#title').val('System Administrator');
$('#phone').val('555-555-5555');
$('#mobile').val('555-777-8888');
$('#email').val('jdoe' + '@ryder.com');
```

I'm a novice at javascript and jQuery.  Just trying to learn by doing something useful here.

Comment: What is the issue you're running into? Seems to be working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/s519ysrn/

Comment: Hmm...  I'm getting nothing.  No errors and no fields being populated.  This is on a page with multiple tabs and a different form in each tab so I'm wondering if I'm not defining enough to get the elements to populate in the right tab?

Comment: Actually, I did find an error in Firebug console.

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$("#username").val("jdoe");

Comment: That means that either jQuery is not being loaded or there is [a conflict](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)